# resizing images for stereo calibration

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I try to stereo calibrate 2 different cameras.
It turned out that images should be the same size. But in my case resolution is different (1920x1080 and 2048x1024).
I'm not sure that change resolution of images of one of cameras is a good idea.
What is the best solution in this situation? Should I change resolution, if yes for what images (reduce big resolution to smaller or vice versa)?

Comment: I think you should try crop the images to the smallest common resolution in each axis. After cropping, the resolution of the first image will be 1920x1024, and the second image be 1920x1024. Cropping the center: `J = I(1+(end-1024)/2:(end+1024)/2, 1+(end-1920)/2:(end+1920)/2, :)`

Comment: You need to know the internal parameters of both cameras as you must take into account the world size of the fields of view. Just cropping may be wrong.